# Leveling sheetrock

Tags: drywall

I had a big leak in the bathroom ceiling, and the sheetrock guy removed it not by cutting the edges, but by pulling it until it stopped pealing off the walls.  4 months later the idiot put up the the new sheetrock.  He didn't tape the corners or mud properly.  And the new sheetrock is 1/2 to 3/4 inches higher than the rest of the ceiling.  And the walls he messed up aren't right.  I informed the owner of the shoddie work, but I don't know if or when the guy will be back to fix it.  I have lots of extra time in the winter.  If he does not fix it, how would I fix it?  This is the only issue in a great appartment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like 1/2" to 3/4" in the photo but if it is it needs to be cut out. The studs should be shimmed 1/2" to 3/4" and a new piece of drywall screwed in and finished properly.

Comment: So, you're a tenant, right? Stop looking at the problem. It's not your responsibility and if you don't have an explicit agreement with the landlord, you almost certainly aren't authorized to do any work on the place.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate If the drywall work fails or looks terrible upon moving out then the landlord isn't too shy to blame the tenant and withhold deposit money. At minimum OP should inform the landlord once the work is complete. If OP has the skills to fix the issue then that could be discussed for potential rent reduction.